# MySQL query help needed for join with common and uncommon rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a very simple query to make in MySQL which joins a single column from Table "second" to Table "firsts".
Data in Table 1:

| Mobile | Name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SHAH WALI | House 00 |
| 111111111 | Himmad Khan | House 11 |
| 222222222 | ABDULLAH | House 22 |
| 333333333 | ABDUL WAHID | House 33 |
| 444444444 | ALAM KHAN | House 44 |
| 555555555 | Saida Gul | House 55 |

Data in Table 2:

| Mobile | Name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SHAH WALI | Lahore |
| 111111111 | Himmad Khan | Islamabad |
| 222222222 | ABDULLAH | Faislabad |
| 666666666 | Wajid khan | Multan |
| 777777777 | Shah Alam | Karachi |
| 888888888 | Momin khan | Dina |

Query I have made as of now:

```
SELECT  f.Mobile, f.Name, f.address, s.city
FROM firsts f
INNER JOIN second s
ON f.Mobile=s.Mobile
```

Results I am getting:

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqruh.png)

Issue:
It only joins the common values from mobile field but i also want the remaining rows i know some fields don't  have city and some don't have address So a null in there place is fine.

Expected result:

| Mobile | NAME | address | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SHAH WALI | House 11 | Lahore |
| 111111111 | Himmad Khan | House 11 | Islamabad |
| 222222222 | ABDULLAH | House 22 | Faislabad |
| 333333333 | ABDUL WAHID | House 33 | NULL |
| 444444444 | ALAM KHAN | House 44 | NULL |
| 555555555 | Saida Gul | House 55 | NULL |
| 666666666 | Wajid khan | NULL | Multan |
| 777777777 | Shah Alam | NULL | Karachi |
| 888888888 | Momin khan | NULL | Dina |

[Please see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cf8bd/1)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output if anything is not working yet

Comment: Thanks for commenting, i did it now but it missed 6, 7, 8 from second table.

Comment: Gather all existing values in the subquery then join both tables to it.

Comment: SELECT  f.Mobile, f.Name, f.address, s.city
FROM firsts f
LEFT JOIN second s
ON f.Mobile=s.Mobile

Comment: Check the question again i have attached both tables. firsts and second.

Comment: @Akina i wish you can help me with an example query as i am very noob.

Comment: Do this: *Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output if anything is not working yet – Nico Haase*. Share == provide according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: one second i am creating the sql fiddle.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Post the sample data as text instead. You can use a tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for formatting.

Comment: Everyone please see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cf8bd/1

Comment: Actually the `address` field for the last three rows should be `NULL` right? I've fixed it.

Comment: yes now its right.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT mobile, COALESCE(first.Name, second.Name) Name, first.Address, second.city
FROM ( SELECT Mobile FROM first
       UNION 
       SELECT Mobile FROM second ) total
LEFT JOIN first USING (Mobile)
LEFT JOIN second USING (Mobile)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=665eba315f059d307c7f6cf3b0362c8a

PS. It is possible that `first.Name <> second.Name`. In my query `first.Name` is preferred - when both is set then `second.Name` is ignored. If you want to see both names then use CONCAT_WS().

Comment: Unrecognized keyword near name.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this:

```
SELECT  f.Mobile, f.Name, f.address, s.city
FROM firsts f
FULL OUTER JOIN second s ON f.Mobile = s.Mobile;
```

but MySQL and MariaDB still don't support full outer joins. Hence you must emulate this. One way:

```
select mobile, max(name), max(address), max(city)
from
(
  select mobile, name, address, null as city from firsts
  union all
  select mobile, name, null as address, city from second
) both_tables
group by mobile;
```

Comment: error on both queries.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN second s ON f.Mobile = s.Mobile LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3
# unexpected keyword near both

Comment: instead of both a unique value worked like this:
select Mobile, max(Name), max(address), max(city)
from
(
  select Mobile, Name, address, null as city from firsts
  union all
  select Mobile, Name, null as address, city from second
) ts
group by Mobile;

Comment: Ah, okay, so `BOTH` is a reserved word in MySQL - and MariaDB for that matter. I see from your error messages that you are using MariaDB, so you should not tag your request `mysql` but `mariadb`. While MariaDB's root is MySQL, their current features may be different.